# What is angular 2 diagnostics comments and how it is used?

Tags: javascript, angular

While using structure directive like *ngIf template, it looks like angular inserts diagnostics comments in the source.

1) Why is it useful, and how is it used later?

2) Is this how angular 2 dynamically adds the template within *ngIf?

When using

```
 <ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
 <div>{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Angular inserts the following comment within html.

[image]

Comment: They are the dom placeholder to know where to put the element when condition is true. HTML comments are also dom nodes (nodeType==9)

Comment: Ok, so if I removed the comment during run time, the placement would not work even if I'm using AOT?

Comment: Would be problematic when condition changes

Comment: Do you think everytime when we do the switch with template *ngIF, it places the same component (with state entact) or re-initialized component?

Comment: @ZammyPage it's gonna create a new component everytime. If you worry about that, use `[hidden]` instead

Comment: @HarryNinh, I do not think so, because as soon as I close the component and re-open it , the state are all intact. (may be because the garbage collector has not happened yet?)

Comment: @ZammyPage little plnkr to prove my words http://plnkr.co/edit/Uf5u3ncNHhUNIPYD9AgW?p=preview check the console to see the constructor being hit every time you re-open the widget.

Comment: Thanks @HarryNinh. Indeed! However, when I was using the kendo UI in my project, it somehow used the same widget, not re-initialized it. I wonder why! .

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 have two type directives one is structural directive and other is attribute directive. *ngIf and *ngFor is structural directive which is render html on bases of condition true/false. on false condition it's showing commented code as you have describe above. For more details [Click here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)